# Confusion in solution of two probability questions

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Weblink to $1$st question and its solution :-

https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/a-speaks-the-truth-3-times-out-of-4-and-b-speaks-the-truth-2/

Weblink to $2$nd question and its solution :-

https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/a-man-is-known-to-speak-the-truth-3-out-of-4-times-he-throws-3/

My confusion is that in the first question we make an extra $\frac{1}{5}*\frac{1}{5}$ multiplication in the second case of total probability (where $2$ didn't show up on the die but still both $A$ and $B$ assert that it was a $2$) to account for the total number of ways of making the lie that $2$ came up but it didn't ( $\frac{1}{5}$ for each person)

Now in second question, in second case of total probability (where $6$ didn't show up on the die but still the man says it is a $6$). Now in this case we do not make that multiplication to account for the total number of ways of speaking the lie that $2$ didn't come up but he still says it is a $2$. Why we didn't make a $\frac{1}{5}$ multiplication here?

Please explain with other situational examples if possible, I am weak in probability. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your confusion.  The $\frac{1}{5}\cdot \frac{1}{5}$ shows up in the first problem to account for the chance that given that it wasn't a $2$ that was rolled and given that both persons were lying that both persons chose to lie and say that it was actually a $2$... this, of course, assuming that each person's lie is independent of one another and the possible lies are explicitly the possible values on the die which did not appear and each lie is equally likely to have been said...  For instance, the liar won't ever choose to say as his lie that the moon is made of cheese.

Comment: Now... to be fair, the linked answer labeled that probability wrong.  That should have been $\Pr(\text{both say it is a 2}\mid \text{it is actually not a 2 and both chose to lie})=\frac{1}{5}\times\frac{1}{5}$.  It is a conditional probability

Comment: @JMoravitz But then why we didn't multiply by 1/5 in second question as well when considering the case that 6 didn't come up on the die and he chose to lie, When he lies he says any random number except the number which actually came on the dice so 1/5 chance he says 2 when it is not actually a 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right.  Something is wrong with their solution or they are making additional or different assumptions than are common for the problem.

Let us first make a few assumptions.  The man chooses to lie or tell the truth independently of the result of the die.  If the man lies, he will uniformly select at random a number from the numbers on the die that didn't appear and his lie to us is that the die shows the selected number.  If the man tells the truth, his truth he tells is the number showing on the die.  The die is standard and fair.

These match with the assumptions seemingly made in the first linked problem (*which has the additional hypothesis that the two people being observed make their decisions independently*)

Letting $A$ be the event a six was rolled, $B$ the event he lies, $C$ the event that he says it was a six (*whether truthfully or a lie*), we are asked to find $\Pr(A\mid C)$, that is... the probability that a six was actually rolled given that we were told that it was a six.

We have $\Pr(A\mid C)=\dfrac{\Pr(A\cap C)}{\Pr(C)}=\dfrac{\Pr(C\mid A)\Pr(A)}{\Pr(C)}=\dfrac{\Pr(C\mid A)\Pr(A)}{\Pr(C\cap A)+\Pr(C\cap A^c)}$

Now, the numerator we can see as being $\frac{3}{4}\times \frac{1}{6}$ as the only way he says it is a six given that it actually is a six is by telling the truth.

The denominator's first term is the same as the numerator.  The denominator's second term however should expand as $\Pr(C\cap A^c) = \Pr(A^c)\Pr(B\mid A^c)\Pr(C\mid B\cap A^c) = \frac{5}{6}\times\frac{1}{4}\color{red}{\times\frac{1}{5}}$.

The linked answer makes the seemingly invalid assumption that $\Pr(C\mid B\cap A^c)=1$, that if the die did not show a six and the man chose to lie that he always says that it is a six.

With the assumptions made above, this results in a final probability of $\dfrac{3}{4}$ that he was telling the truth about what he saw on the die when he said it was a six.

---

Now, to be fair, perhaps the original question writer intended the man to answer only yes or no questions.  We the observer asked the man the yes or no question "Was a six rolled" to which if it was and he was telling the truth he would say "yes," or if it wasn't and he were lying he would say "yes."  Otherwise he would have simply said "no."

The end result is that questions like this should be incredibly specific about the actions and decision making process behind what information is shared.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this in detail. So I think it all comes down to the additional information (which is absent in both the questions) that whether the person chooses a random number when he lies or whether he chooses a fixed number every time he lies. Both of these questions have appeared in mathematical competitive exams in the past, what should I do if it comes in my competitive exam? leave it or attempt it? The probability of my answer being correct 1/4 of course :)

Comment: @AmanJain that's a tough question.  If there is a proctor you can ask, flag one and ask for clarification. If they refuse, then request the problem be reconsidered by the judges at which point it may be thrown out.  Otherwise, if it were free-form answer format then make an assumption and state what assumptions you made as to the intended interpretation.